# Usage of already without have/has

Tags: grammaticality

Are the following sentences grammatical?
I have been learnt that "already" needs to accompany  "have/has," as in:

> I have already eaten the food
>
> The food has already been eaten by me

But I am curious: are the following sentences grammatical?

> I already eat the food.
>
> The food is already eaten.
>
> I already ate the food.
>
> The food was already eaten.

Comment: *Have been learnt* is problematic in so-called standard English. It would be standard to say *have been taught* or *have learnt*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all four sentences are grammatical, at least in certain contexts (which is always the case). So the use of "[already](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/already)" is not limited to the present perfect (have/had plus past participle). See "More Example Sentences" at that dictionary link.

In addition, the present perfect does not require "already". So your opening two sentences can be written without "already."

You might want to look at the search results for ["already" in previous questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=Already+) for more examples of usage.